# React Native, when I generate the android apk it comes with a white bar at the top where the notch is, how to remove it?

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm programming through expo, when I test it on my cell phone the app is filling the entire screen normally, after testing I create the apk using the command eas build -p android --profile preview, download the APK and install it on my android cell phone, however when I install it there is always a white bar at the top of all screens, I've tried everything but I can't remove it from the APK, when I'm testing it through expo everything is fine, the problem is only in the APK, does anyone know how to remove this bar top white?

[how is it in the apk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPTR0.jpg)

[how it looks at the expo, it's the way I want it to look, it's the same code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJ9Lg.jpg)

Below is an example of code from one of the screens:

```js
    return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/fundog02.jpg')} style={ styles.imgBack}>
      <ScrollView showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}>

      <View style={styles.areaIcone}>
        <Image source={require('../../assets/saude.png')} style={ styles.imgIcone }/>
        <Text style={styles.textoIcone}> Saúde </Text>
      </View>

      <View style={styles.areaBoxes}>
                    <View style={styles.box1}>
                        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/fundo04.jpg')} imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10}} style={ styles.imgBox }>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Hospitais')}>
                                <View style={ styles.areaConteudo }>
                                    <Image source={require('../../assets/hospital.png')} style={styles.imgIconeBox}/>
                                    <Text style={styles.textoBox}> Hospitais </Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </ImageBackground>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.box1}>
                        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/fundo04.jpg')} imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10}} style={ styles.imgBox }>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('UAPS')}>
                                <View style={ styles.areaConteudo }>
                                    <Image source={require('../../assets/upa128.png')} style={styles.imgIconeBox}/>
                                    <Text style={styles.textoBox}> UAPS </Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </ImageBackground>
                    </View>

            </View>

            <View style={styles.areaBoxes}>
                    <View style={styles.box2}>
                        <ImageBackground source={require('../../assets/fundo04.jpg')} imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 10}} style={ styles.imgBox }>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Vacinas')}>
                                <View style={ styles.areaConteudo }>
                                    <Image source={require('../../assets/vacina.png')} style={styles.imgIconeBox}/>
                                    <Text style={styles.textoBox}> Vacinas </Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                        </ImageBackground>
                    </View>

            </View>
            </ScrollView>
      </ImageBackground>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#1C1C1C',
  },
  imgBack:{
    flex: 1,
    height: '100%',
    width: '100%',
    resizeMode: "cover"
  },
  imgIcone:{
    height: 100,
    width: 100,
},
areaIcone:{
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginBottom: '5%',
    marginTop: '15%'
},
textoIcone:{
    fontSize: 30,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
    textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
    textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
    textShadowRadius: 10,
},
box1:{
    width: '45%',
    borderRadius: 20,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    marginTop: '2%',
    shadowColor: "#000",
    shadowOffset: {
        width: 0,
        height: 2,
    },
    shadowOpacity: 0.25,
    shadowRadius: 3.84,
    elevation: 5,
    marginHorizontal: '1%'
    },
    box2:{
        width: '90%',
        borderRadius: 20,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: '2%',
        shadowColor: "#000",
        shadowOffset: {
            width: 0,
            height: 2,
        },
        shadowOpacity: 0.25,
        shadowRadius: 3.84,
        elevation: 5,
        marginHorizontal: '1%'
        },
    imgBox:{
        flex: 1,
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    areaBoxes:{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    areaConteudo:{
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        marginTop: '10%'
    },
    imgIconeBox:{
        width: 70,
        height: 70,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    textoBox:{
        fontSize: 20,
        fontWeight: 'bold',
        color: 'white',
        paddingTop: 15,
        paddingBottom: 20,
        textShadowColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
        textShadowOffset: {width: -1, height: 1},
        textShadowRadius: 10,
        textAlign: 'center'
    },
});
```

The navigator:

```js
 <Stack.Navigator>
             <Stack.Screen name='Saude' component={Saude} options={{ headerTransparent: true, headerTintColor: 'white', headerTitle: '' }} />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

i try safeAreaView and paddingTop: 0 but nothings works, I hope the apk is the same as the test version of the expo

Comment: Facing same issue, what solution did you go with

Answer (score 1):

If this is still actual - you can try this:
https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/status-bar/

I faced this very same annoying issue yesterday.
And just did this:

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';

<StatusBar style="light" />
```

Hope this help

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I managed to solve it by adding the following clause to the app.json file

     "androidStatusBar": {
       "translucent": true
     }

After that the white bar of the apk disappeared, it was perfect, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve it by adding the following clause to the app.json file

```
 "androidStatusBar": {
   "translucent": true
 }
```

After that the white bar of the apk disappeared, it was perfect, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Could you just put, if you not need the navigator header.

```bash
options={{ headerShown: false }}
```

its solved ?

Comment: I tried but it didn't work, I managed to solve it by adding the following clause to the app.json file

     "androidStatusBar": {
       "translucent": true
     }

After that the white bar of the apk disappeared, it was perfect, thanks for the help